# Heroku review app won't build with multiple buildpacks

Tags: heroku, buildpack

https://twitter.com/jfeldstein/status/705914506610810880

Multi buildpacks don't seem to work with review apps.

I'm using these packs http://cl.ly/04210t150P3w

Yet my review app fails to build with the message http://cl.ly/211Z240q183r

Review apps are currently beta. Do they not support environments built on multiple buildpacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the `app.json` file. :shame: